# Mutate function to columns except few cells

Tags: r

I have got a dataset where I need to round of values for few columns at once. I have applied mutate function to do this. But in the columns there are some texts as well that needs to excluded, For example,

```
df 
ColA   ColB      ColC
A     56.568     45.590
B     60.596      B
C     A          78.456

df1 <- df %>% mutate_at(vars(ColB, ColC),funs(round(.,1)))
```

But since the columns contains characters,I am not able to execute it. Expected output is

```
df1
ColA   ColB    ColC
A     56.5     45.5
B     60.5      B
C     A        78.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a character and number in the same column, it defaults to character and you cannot round it.

You have to use a custom function:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(
   ColA=c("A","B","C"),
   ColB=c(56.568,60.596,"A"),
   ColC=c(45.590,"B",78.456)
            )
# you can see they are converted to factor
str(df)
###function to round numbers and convert them back to characters
convertCol = function(x){
y = round(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(as.character(x))),1)
y = as.character(y)
y[is.na(y)] = as.character(x[is.na(y)])
y
}
df %>% map_df(convertCol)
```

Still, it is not possible to have both a character and number in the same column.. And switching between one and the other can be quite insane